# Not able to see xbox live user status for friends?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, xbox-one, xbox-live

Developing an xbox application using UWP. I would like to see the status of my signed in user on one xbox to the friends of the user. For Example, in device(Xbox) one signed in user is User1 and in device two signed in user is User2. Also the User1 and User2 are friends each other.

Now when the user1 runs the App say App1 in device2, under friends list of the user2 we should be able to see the status "App1 Xbox" for user1.

I am getting this behavior by default. But I would like to change the status from "App1 Xbox" to "App1".

Anybody have any idea on how to do this from within the application?

Another scenario is like in device1 with user1 signed in open the settings App, it just shows the status as "Settings" for user2 in device2. Like that I would like to see "App1" instead of "App1 Xbox".

Comment: Please share the `c#` code you've wrote.

Comment: I haven't wrote any c# code to work this feature. Its by default.

Comment: `c#` tag on you question suppose that you've have some code or expect that c# code can resolve your question. At least, can you share `xaml` code in order to help people reproduce the problem?

Comment: Its pretty difficult to share the code for this scenario. Its a general question on xbox I believe.

Comment: Might be better to ask the question on GameDev site : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JonathanLarouche Thanks.